# Select which argument you want to set when they are more than one default in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments, default

How can I set the second argument in a method with three?

For example:

```
def method(arg1=5, arg2="something", arg3=12)
end
```

How would I set the second argument without having to do this:

```
method(arg1=5, "something_else", arg3=12)
```

Comment: do you mean setting second argument when calling the method?

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use named parameters by using ":" instead of "=", you code can be :

```
def method(arg1: 5, arg2: "something", arg3: 12)
end
```

then you can call the method by setting the value for the argument you need :

```
method(arg2: "something_else")
```